# How to determine what is between divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sounds like a simple question:

We have to similar divs:

- `<div class='child'></div>`
- `<div class='child'>SMTH SMTH</div>`

How do I determine that the first one has 0 value and the second one is populated? Is there any specific jQuery or JS function?

Comment: @JTSmith. Upvoters, though that comment is true and I upvoted it as well, what about the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406490/how-to-determine-what-is-between-divs#comment13424821_10406506)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`empty` selector](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/), possibly combined with [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) to determine if *at least one* of the matched elements meets the given selector.

```
var empty = $(".child:empty"); // gets empty elements with class child
var isEmpty $(".child").first().is(":empty"); // determines if the first .child div is empty.
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/txeEE/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `test()` API of jQuery, or `innerHTML` and `textContent` of DOM specify.

```
<div class="child"><b>test</b> content</div>

<script>
    var child = document.querySelector('.child');
    alert(child.innerHTML); // <b>test</b> content
    alert(child.textContent); // test content

    var $child = $('.child');
    alert($child.text()); // test content
</script>
```

Comment: Replace `text()` with `html()`

Comment: @gdoron `test()` and `html()` are two different API

Answer (score 0):

There is the [textContent](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#Node3-textContent) property in browsers that support the W3C DOM Core methods and [innerText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for those that support IE's model. Some browsers support both.

So you can do:

```
if (!(el.textContent || el.innerText)) {
  // element has no text content
}
```